# Dependency Over two DIV

Tags: html, resize

I have 2 different DIV,the one is for left **(600px)**, and the other is for right (300px). In left side the contend is displaying. and the right is sidebar. now i want when i disable my sidebar from back end. the left side content automatically increase. i mean left DIV automatically take width 900. and when i enable the sidebar the left DIV automatically take width 600, so that sidebar and content display together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this script:

```
$(function(){
    var sidebarIsHidden  = $('#sidebar').css('display') == 'none' ? true: false;
    if(sidebarIsHidden)
    {
        $('#content').css('width','900px');
    }
});
```

You have to check to see if the sidebar is disabled or not. I used `display` for demonstration purposes only. You have to use your own check.

Comment: Thanks Saeed, I Managed it Accordingly and it works Fine. Thanks for Your Help.

Comment: Your welcome, :), if this answer helped you, mark it as the answer, so others find it easier ;)